# chosen js new line

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-chosen

I am currently displaying the selected value in my chosen js.

Here is the view
[image]

As you can see my select box does not render all words. 
I want to see the text value on a new line

I already have tried this code but it seems that nothing happens

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```css
div#doctrine_doctrinecontent_attributes_topic_id_chosen {
    display: inline;
}
```

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
    allow_single_deselect: true,
    no_results_text: 'No results matched',
    width: '100%',
});
```

Comment: Are you using jquery? Its probably jquery or javascript that making this happen, clarify the question.

Comment: im using jquery

Comment: It seems like chosen doesn't contain any option which would allow you to do that, you can simply edit the library itself or create your own.

Comment: clarify the question

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding these two styles in your CSS file.

```
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
  height: auto;
}

.chosen-container-single .chosen-single span {
    word-break: break-all;
    white-space: initial;
}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry for the late reply let me check this